# How to use two database of mongoose in my node.js website?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I am creating a Todo List website for which I need two databases, one for storing user's information and another for storing list items. But I don't know how to use two databases of mongoose in the same node.js project. (note: I have also used ejs and express).

Comment: quick question why do you have two databases, instead of one any specific use case ?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to MongoDB. Can you please tell me how can I create and store two different schemas in the same dtatbase

Comment: add a collection

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Creating Two Databases you Should/can create one database with two collections

or if you really want to use two databases create 2 connections

ex.

````
In foo_db_connect.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/foo_db');
module.exports = exports = mongoose;```

In bar_db_connect.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bar_db');
module.exports = exports = mongoose;```
````

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please give an example how to do it.

Comment: just create two different models/schema

Answer (score 0):

You can create two collections (users, items) in the same database for your usecase.Check [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)